JavaNature cannot be cast to IJavaProject when using Hibernate with Java Project
I'm a beginner in Advanced Java and recently started learning Hibernate. While creating Hibernate Configuration file I'm getting this error:
Here is the img of Error
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaNature cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject (org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaNature and org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject are in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @59ebd3be)

Firstly i'm getting the hibernate.dialect not set. then i get to know that i have to configure MySQl details on hibernate config file. but after selecting the cfg.xml and click on next i get this error. how can i solve this error or is there any other way to set this configurations.

I've had this error several times. Some of the times I could get rid of it by installing any pending Eclipse/plugin updates. You could try that.

@RobSpoor There is no pending updates

I was getting the same error and I was also following the telusko video. What I did was instead of right clicking on the project folder to create new hibernate.cfg.xml file you should click on the src/main/java folder, and it works fine for me. Maybe in new updates it will be fixed properly.
